# How to show WordPress author.php when user has no posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, profile, author

So I have been building author.php pages to display user profiles.

This relies on 'if ( have_posts() ) :' at top, where - FYI - I also have...

`<?php
                /* Queue the first post, that way we know
                 * what author we're dealing with (if that is the case).
                 *
                 * We reset this later so we can run the loop
                 * properly with a call to rewind_posts().
                 */
                the_post();
            ?>`

`<?php
                /* Since we called the_post() above, we need to
                 * rewind the loop back to the beginning that way
                 * we can run the loop properly, in full.
                 */
                rewind_posts();
            ?>`

That's fine if the user in question *has* any posts to his/her name.
But, when they have zero posts, the profile page comes up blank where there should be content.

How can I overcome this?

FYI, full author.php is...

`

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /* Queue the first post, that way we know
             * what author we're dealing with (if that is the case).
             *
             * We reset this later so we can run the loop
             * properly with a call to rewind_posts().
             */
            the_post();
        ?>

        <?php
            /* Since we called the_post() above, we need to
             * rewind the loop back to the beginning that way
             * we can run the loop properly, in full.
             */
            rewind_posts();
        ?>

        <?php
        /* Get Extra User Fields*/
        $values_by_name = array(  // Assign defaults to all CIMY fields
            'TITLEJOB' => '',
            'TITLESECONDARY' => '',
            'COMPANY' => '',
        );
        $values = get_cimyFieldValue($author, false);
        if ($values) {
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $values_by_name[$value['NAME']] = cimy_uef_sanitize_content($value['VALUE']);
            }
        }
        ?>

        <h1><?php the_author(); ?></h1>

        <?php
        if(!empty($values_by_name['COMPANY'])) {
            echo '<p>Company: '.$values_by_name['COMPANY'].'</p>';
        }

        if(!empty($values_by_name['TITLEJOB'])) {
            echo '<p>Title: '.$values_by_name['TITLEJOB'].'</p>';

            if(!empty($values_by_name['TITLESECONDARY'])) {
                echo '<p>Secondary: '.$values_by_name['TITLESECONDARY'].'</p>';
            }

        }
        ?>

        <?php

        ?>

        <p><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' )); ?></p>
        <p>URL: <a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url' ); ?>"><?php the_author_meta( 'user_url' ); ?></a></p>
        <p>Description: <?php echo nl2br(get_the_author_meta( 'description' )); ?></p>

        <h4>Posts: <?php the_author_posts(); ?></h4>
        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <ul>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>

        <h4>Topics</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Topic</li>
            <li>Topic</li>
            <li>Topic</li>
        </ul>

        <h4>Companies</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Company</li>
            <li>Company</li>
            <li>Company</li>
        </ul>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

`

Comment: A plugin exists to solve this but which does not work on my site. Code goes...    `if (!function_exists('show_authors_without_posts')) {
 
 function show_authors_without_posts($template) {
  global $wp_query;
  if( !is_author() && get_query_var('author') && (0 == $wp_query->posts->post) ) {
   // debug
   // echo 'Overwrite default 404 template...';
   return get_author_template();
  }
  return $template;
 }
 
 add_filter('404_template', 'show_authors_without_posts');
}`Is there anything wrong with this that requires changes to work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not make your own query?

```
haveno_posts{

    If Posts = 0 then return true?

}

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

would be

```
<?php if ( have_posts() || haveno_posts() ) : ?>
```

alternatively:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/show-authors-without-posts/admin/

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/show-author-archive-pages-for-authors-with-no-posts

Comment: I think this is something to do with what values can be accessed inside/outside The Loop (?). The plugin doesn't work for me; I left a message with the developer. I have looked at the discussion's guidance, basically about using get_userdata. What is a full list of values I can access using get_userdata? Because so far I don't see I can pull in values equivalent to the current method, including avatar.

Comment: The full list is either in the database itself, I would assume in _users

Answer (score 0):

You have the full page content wrapped in the conditional:

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
```

It would stand to reason that if the user has no posts, it jumps to the bottom and displays nothing...

Comment: Without this, the author page for zero-post authors lacks the author name, avatar and URL fields amongst others, and throws a strange post count of "9" in one case.

Comment: That is, removing the "if" clause shows some fields - both for authors with and without posts. Now, for with-post authors that previously had full profile pages, there is missing info. I am missing something about the way I can access this info outside/inside, I think...